# Running R script in VBA Wrong Directory

Tags: r, windows, vba, excel

I have a macro that edits an R script.
That R script is then supposed to be called by the following VBA:

```
 Dim shell As Object
 Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
 Dim style As Integer: style = 1
 Dim errorCode As Integer
 Dim path As String

 path = """" & "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\i386\R.exe" & """ """ & "R RAM Cluster Script.R" & """"

 errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
```

The above code was from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597626/running-r-scripts-from-vba).

When I execute the macro, however, the R Command Line gives me an error stating:

```
 '\\dm\home\myaccount\*Path of my original Excel File*'
 "CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. 
  UNC Paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory. 
  Argument 'R  RAM Cluster Script.R' Ignored"
```

The script is stored in the folder that my Excel workbook is in.

Can anyone help me out with finding my problem?

Comment: what happens if you try to run the **R script** by replacing the last line with `shell.Run path, 1, True` ? does it work ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no-- I get the same error.

Comment: where is this file stored R RAM Cluster Script.R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
 Dim shell As Object
 Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
 Dim style As Integer: style = 1
 Dim errorCode As Integer
 Dim path As String


 path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\RScript.exe""" & """c:/temp/R RAM Cluster Script.R"""

 errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)

End Sub
```

Comment: Change the r.exe to rscript.exe for batch arguments.

Comment: Try adding the path to the R file 'c:\YOUR DIR\R RAM ...' in your argument.  The error is due to rscript not finding the script.

Comment: One more try?  c:/mypath  note change in slash direction

Comment: To anyone reading, use this code that PhilC posted-- It works perfectly!

Note for 32-bit R users: use RScript.exe within folder i386

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to use powershell as a wrapper for your script because it DOES support UNC paths. So, something like this should work:

```
path = "Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -Command &{'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\i386\R.exe " &  ThisWorkbook.Path & "\R RAM Cluster Script.R'}"
```

Comment: This did help get around the directory problem, but because of the space between 'Program' and 'Files', it is looking for an executable called `C:\Program`

Comment: ah, i'll fix my answer then

Comment: Now I have received an unexpected token error for PowerShell.
It says:

Comment: thinking about it, it might be that it is not expecting there to be two strings. i'll edit again

Comment: actually i found the reason you may have a problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246735/unexpected-token-errors-in-powershell