# VBA Shell for Runnin R Script

Tags: r, excel, vba

I want to create Tool in Excel through which I can run R Scritpts I have. Can any one help to do that. I am new to VBA codes and have very limited knowledge

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449934/run-r-script-in-excel?